# Python3 OpenCV detect only one eye

Tags: python, opencv

I am quite new to OpenCV, and I have made a small program that detects a left eye from a video stream, and draws a box around it.

It does this using [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml) haar cascade.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2

videoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("leftEye.xml") # from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml

streamWidth = int(videoCapture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
streamHeight = int(videoCapture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

while True:
    _, normalFrame = videoCapture.read()
    normalFrameGrayOverlay = cv2.cvtColor(normalFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    eyes = cascade.detectMultiScale(normalFrameGrayOverlay, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

    for (x, y, w, h) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(normalFrameGrayOverlay, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 0), 2)
        print("X" + str(x) + "Y" + str(y))

    cv2.imshow("ArduinoFaceDetection", normalFrameGrayOverlay)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

videoCapture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, when I start the stream, it highlights multiple eyes at once (and sometimes the wall, but that's just my horrible camera). I was wondering if there was a way to only target one eye (preferably the left eye, as the haar cascade states), so that I don't get a flood of information from the `print("X" + str(x) + "Y" + str(y))` line.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried increasing minimum neighbours number to around 22?